# Create a custom decorator "@" to import a module from it's parent directory (ReactJs)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'd like to import a module from a directory using a custom decorator/annotation like `@material-ui/core` module, like the example below :

Instead of classic import

```
import class1 from '../../../../Services/module1';
```

I'd like to use this syntaxe

```
import class1 from '@Services/module1';
```

Thank's for your help !

Comment: This is not a decorator or annotation. The use of incorrect terms doesn't help to get a correct answer. *like @material-ui/core module* - it's not anything like that. @material-ui is package scope, https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope . What you're trying to do is an alias, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749973/es6-import-using-at-sign-in-path-in-a-vue-js-project-using-webpack . It's very specific to your setup which wasn't explained. If you're using Webpack directly, that's one thing. If you're using CRA, it's another.

Comment: @estus im using CRA

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50132624/how-to-add-import-shortcuts-alias . You may want to change Webpack config with react-app-rewired instead of ejecting CRA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using [`babel-plugin-module-resolver`](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver)

Specify the plugin in your `.babelrc` with the custom root or alias. Here's an example:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./src"],
      "alias": {
        "~": "./app",
        "underscore": "lodash"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: without ejecting ?

Comment: actually, there are two solutions check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/47966412/6017880

Comment: you can put that directly in your package.json

Answer (score 1):

In TS:

```
"paths": {
      "@app/*": ["app/*"],
      "@env/*": ["environments/*"]
}
```

In the compilerOptions in your tsconfig.json file.

In Webpack: [How can I use shortcut path "@" in webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48577695/how-can-i-use-shortcut-path-in-webpack)

Comment: @bigHorse, im using Js not TS ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have to eject my reactJs project (created using CRA) -> edit webpack.config.js -> Add an alias :

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      '@pages': path.join(__dirname, '/src/pages'),
      '@components': path.join(__dirname, '/src/components'),
      '@assets': path.join(__dirname, '/src/assets'),
    },
  },
```